# Getting xml string from Document in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a Java program aiming to consider an xml dom and write it into a string.
I am using these packages: `org.w3c.dom.*` and `javax.xml.parsers.*;`

So I have `DocumentBuilder`, `Document`, `Element` objects...

Is there a way to get the string representing my xml dom in one call????

Comment: Sure - take Grammin's solution and extract it to a method - then you have *one call*: `String xml = serialize(document);`

Comment: Well it is different... wrapping is not always te best solution :) however hank you :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its not one call but:

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", Integer.toString(2));

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement());

trans.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

The setOutputProperty method makes the string output prettier so you can take it out.

Comment: ok... but isn't this a call to xml transformation?? is it really necessary? is it possible that this library doesn not implement a tostring in order to get this goal?... however thank you. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String xmlString =  org.apache.ws.security.util.XMLUtils.PrettyDocumentToString(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.PrettyDocumentToString(Document) have a problem that includes white spaces in the tag values.

A solution is use the method org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.DocumentToString(Document).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a cheap and efficient way to serialize a DOM. Until now, I see only 2 options:

- JAXP transformations (something like Grammin)
- LSSerializer like here: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-3.

Maybe you can try the LSSerializer approach (but not in one call).

Comment: Well, yes it is a good approach and I tried it and works... thankyou