# Serialize a Document object in Java, while preserving the formatting of arbitrary elements

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I am using the function below to convert a DOM Document object into a String in Java.

```
public static String convertDocumentToString(final Document doc) {
    final DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
    final LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();
    lsSerializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
    final String xml = lsSerializer.writeToString(doc);

    return xml;
}
```

This works well most of the time, but there is are some specific elements that I don't want formatted (e.g. the screen DocBook element). So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to skip certain elements when formatting XML in Java like in the code above?
2. If not, is there another way to convert a Document to a String while preserving the layout of arbitrary elements?

Note that I have also used the Transformer in the past (see [Getting xml string from Document in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794196/getting-xml-string-from-document-in-java)), but that didn't preserve CDATA sections.

**Update:**

Just so I am clear, I am deserializing and serializing XML in order to create a Document object that can be edited programatically via a DOM, with the serialization process preferably "pretty printing" the resulting XML (with the exception of some arbitrary elements).

**Update 2:**

In the end I created a custom function to convert a Node to a String with optional formatting. See the convertNodeToString function at https://sourceforge.net/p/commonclasses/code/110/tree/trunk/src/com/redhat/ecs/commonutils/XMLUtilities.java called like so:

```
final String exampleXml = FileUtilities.readFileContents(new File("test.xml"));

final ArrayList<String> contentsInlineElements = new ArrayList<String>();
contentsInlineElements.add("title");
contentsInlineElements.add("term");

final ArrayList<String> inlineElements = new ArrayList<String>();
inlineElements.add("prompt");
inlineElements.add("command");
inlineElements.add("firstterm");
inlineElements.add("ulink");
inlineElements.add("guilabel");
inlineElements.add("filename");
inlineElements.add("replaceable");
inlineElements.add("parameter");
inlineElements.add("literal");
inlineElements.add("classname");
inlineElements.add("sgmltag");
inlineElements.add("guibutton");
inlineElements.add("guimenuitem");
inlineElements.add("guimenu");
inlineElements.add("menuchoice");
inlineElements.add("citetitle");

final ArrayList<String> verbatimElements = new ArrayList<String>();
verbatimElements.add("screen");
verbatimElements.add("programlisting");

final Document doc = XMLUtilities.convertStringToDocument(exampleXml);
final String formattedXml = XMLUtilities.convertNodeToString(doc.getDocumentElement(), true, false, false, verbatimElements, inlineElements, contentsInlineElements, true, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is designed to get data across a transport medium, but not necessarily (or even usually) in a way that is true to the form of the input data, if that form is by definition not carrying any extra information (as is the case with XML documents).

If you need to carry over the design, too, you will have to encode this "meta" information (i. e. the formatting) into the data itself, for example by escaping whitespace etc. Maybe the easiest solution, but one that will keep you from simply "reading" (as in with your eyes) the transport stream, is to encode your formatted data in something like Base64. This will perfectly transport inside an XML wrapper, while at the same time conserving the fidelity of the original input data you fed into the encoder.

On the other side, of course, you will have to decode the data again, before you can go on processing it further.

Comment: The workflow I use is: 1. deserialize an XML string to create a Document object 2. process the Document object (adding and removing elements) 3. serialize the Document object back to a String, preferably with pretty print. "Serialization" in this case is just a way to create an in memory representation that I can reliably edit the XML via a DOM, as opposed to moving data over a transport medium.

Comment: Hm... I am not aware of any XML lib (although, I haven't looked too hard) that could exclude arbitrary elements from formatting. I am not even sure that this could be implemented and suit all needs. I think you might want to consider the Base64 (or any other) encoding inside the XML. Would at least be a reliable implementation, without having to worry that an update of an XML dependency might break stuff in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you can't. When you tell the serializer to pretty-print, you're making a statement about the use of inter-element whitespace (ie, it's ignorable).

The longer answer: you can't without modifying the DOM (or a copy of it). IMO the simplest way is the following:

1. Identify the node that you want to preserve. I'll assume that you have an ID or some other way to select it using XPath.
2. Call `Document.adoptNode()` to move that node into a new DOM. I recall having some issues with this method, but that was many years ago. If it doesn't work, use `Document.importNode()` and explicitly remove the node from the source document. I *believe* that you can adopt a node as the root of a document, but can't guarantee that.
3. Insert a text node into the original document, containing unique content. An easy way to generate unique content is `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.
4. Convert both documents to strings, pretty-printing one and not pretty-printing the other.
5. Use `String.replace()` to insert the not-pretty-printed document into the pretty-printed document.

And, as always, if you're planning to write those strings to a file or other byte-oriented format, you *must* explicitly encode as UTF-8.

Answer (score -5):

Whitespace is not significant in XML documents other than in CDATA sections, and none of the standard tools is designed to preserve it. Any requirement to the contrary is ill-formed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but whitespace is very significant in XML documents. The only time that it isn't significant ("ignorable whitespace") is when you have a DTD that specifically defines the construct as "element content". See http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#sec-element-content and http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#sec-white-space (particularly the first note)

Comment: OK, now I downvoted. Answer is incorrect and misleading, and you had the opportunity to edit/delete.

Comment: In this case whitespace has a significant impact, despite the fact that it is not in a CDATA section. See http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/screen.html: "This element is displayed “verbatim”; whitespace and line breaks within this element are significant."