# Create XPath from Child Elements

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to add an `XPath` attribute to all `<definition>` tags in my XML document. The XPath's value will come from a nested tag `<term>Test123</term>` inside each `<definition>` tag. I'm using the `import org.w3c.dom.Document;` object. When I run this line with my really long XML file then it tells me that there are 539 instances of the `<definition>` tag:

```
System.out.println(inputDOM.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("definition"));
```

So the end result is that there must be a `Document` object that has set all the definition tags from the term tags, for example

`<definition XPath="Test123"> <term>Test123</term> </definition>`

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about here. Is it how to add the attribute, or how to find the node from the attribute, or something else?

Comment: How to add the `XPath` attribute to the correct nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
NodeList definitionElements = inputDOM.getElementsByTagName("definition");
for (int i = 0; i < definitionElements.getLength(); i++) {
    Element current = (Element) definitionElements.item(i);
    Node term = current.getElementsByTagName("term").item(0);
    if(term != null && term.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        current.setAttribute("XPath", ((Element) term).getTextContent());
}
```

First we get all `<definition>` tags. After that we iterate each `<definition>` tag and set a new attributs "XPath" whose value is the text content of the `<term>` child tag

Comment: Try this: `((Element)current.getElementsByTagName("term")).getTextContent()`

Comment: Thanks. How do I apply these changes to a new `Document` object instance? Or should I just apply it to `inputDOM` variable?

Comment: I think the change are automatically save to your current document.
If you want to get xml string from your document, see this post: [Getting xml string from Document in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794196/getting-xml-string-from-document-in-java)